# loop to clear the contents of a row when a cell is blank

Tags: excel, vba

First day, new job, don't want to fall flat in front of my boss on the first task I've been given. I've tried various IF THEN, FOR & DO statements but can't get quite the behaviour I need.

I have data from column A to AH. I want to click a button, which would cause a loop to check the contents of every cell on column D and then to clear the contents of that row if it comes back empty.

Comment: `I've tried various IF THEN, FOR & DO statements but can't get quite the behaviour I need.` - show please what have you tried so far

Comment: Use something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21328531/445425), with `clear` instead of `delete`

Comment: Has the boss asked you to do something unrelated to the job you accepted or did you pretend you knew VBA?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Sub delDemptyrows()
Dim i&
For i = 1 To ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
    If Cells(i, 4).Value = vbNullString Then Cells(i, 4).EntireRow.ClearContents '4 = D column
Next
End Sub
```

not tested, so make backup before use.

Comment: Thanks, I'm working on a test copy of the data currently, noway they'd let me play with the live DB. If I want to start it from say row 6 onwards, so that I don't mess with the headings etc on the data, I just change the i value?